# ¿ Como visualizar contenido de menu?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, json

He creado un formulario el cual tiene un submenu con diferentes opciones, que al hacer hacer clic tiene que visualizar el contenido de la opción en una parte del mismo formulario. ¿ Existe la posibilidad de realizarlo ?

```
<form>
<div class="submenu">
     <button class="btn">RAMALES</button>
         <li><a href="ramalr1.php">R1 Cristo Rey-Estadio Olímpico</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr2.php">R2 Dolorosa-Estadio Olímpico</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr3.php">R3 Chillogallo-Mariana De Jésus</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr5.php">R5 La Esperanza-San Vicente De Las Casas</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr8.php">R8 Chilibulo-La Magdalena</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr9.php">R9 Santa Rosa III-Hospital Del IESS</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr10.php">R10 Santa Rosa-Vicentina</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr11.php">R11 La Merced-Hospital Del IESS</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr12.php">R12 San Francisco De Asis-Floresta</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr13.php">R13 Estadio Del Aucas-Floresta</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr14.php">R14 La Isla-Las Casas</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr15.php">R15 Mena 2-Hospital Del IESS</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr17.php">R17 Santa Bárbara-Itchimbía</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr18.php">R18 Buenaventura De Chillogallo-Artigas</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr20.php">R20 Girón Del Sur-Santa Clara</a></li>
         <li><a href="ramalr21.php">R21 Quitumbe-Itchimbía-Dorado</a></li>


<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1sEZVSaLX4ujJLdRwd76v0FEno0bePMc1" ></iframe>
</form>
```

Lo que esta en el iframe es lo que se debe visualizar. Por favor pido la colaboración sobre el tema, de antemano muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no me quedó muy claro lo que intentas hacer, Puedes hacerlo usando JavaScript, que te permite Modificar los elementos html sin enviar los datos. 
Crea un botón y le asignas el evento onclick para que te modifique la característica hidden o display. No te preocupes, el tema es fácil, sólo busca algún texto o tutorial de JavaScript con el tema “modificar el DOM”.

Comment: @Elkin muchas gracias, voy a investigar sobre el DOM.